# Did The Dark Knight only make $2.0M at the box office?

Tags: the-dark-knight, box-office

On the [*The Dark Knight's (2008)* Rotten Tomatoes webpage](https://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/the_dark_knight), it says the movie earned ***"$2.0M at the box office (gross USA)"***.

[image: screencap of rotten tomatoes webpage]

---

Two million seems low for such a popular movie.

Were the earnings really that low, or is that an error? For example, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Dark_Knight) lists the box office earnings as $1.006 billion. So which site is right?

Comment: No. That's not right. It broke records at the box office, with $238.6 million in its first week. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Dark_Knight#Box_office It was the highest grossing film of 2008 at the US box office.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### The movie has made over $1 billion to date

Your own instinct is telling you that $2m is likely to be wildly incorrect, as indicated by the amount quoted in Wikipedia, hence the downvotes your question is receiving.

Sites that specialize in movie finances, such as Box Office Mojo will show you [in detail how the movie performed](https://www.boxofficemojo.com/title/tt0468569/?ref_=bo_se_r_1), including:

- Making $158 million in the US opening weekend alone
- Grossing $1.006 billion to date